# How do I redirect apache on Ubuntu server to serve the index.php file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I found a similar question on stack overflow and tried following the directions as specified there for redirecting a request for example.com to load /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.php

I am trying to setup friendly urls.
On Ubuntu, I have a vhost file inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

If I put DirectoryIndex index.php in there, it fails to restart apache.  I do use the a2ensite command on Ubuntu to create the simlink to the sites-enabled directory.

I also tried putting 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.pl
in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf file but still that doesn't load the php file that exists in my directory /var/www/example.com/public_html and then I try to load example.com in the browser.
I read somewhere that posting on stack overflow I should use example.com in place of the actual domain name.

I then found a post on using the .htaccess file to redirect from index.html to index.php.  What I am trying to achieve is to have example.com serve index.php.

Logic suggested that if I edit the /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf and put index.php first and then put the other file types, mime-types after that, it would prefer index.php over index.html

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1index.php [R=301,L]
```

This is in the directory /var/www/example.com/public_html 
which is the DocumentRoot for the domain I am trying to serve.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Or how to get this right?
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: Just using `DirectoryIndex index.php` in vhost file should be enough. Remove the htaccess file, restart server; and check the access and error logs respectively.

Comment: For some reason if I put

Comment: For some reason if I put DirectoryIndex index.php into the vhost file, which on Ubuntu is /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf it fails to start or restart apache.  As it is, if I enter example.com/index.php into the browser, it runs the php file index.php.  However, if I just put in the browser example.com it doesn't try to load index.php   I can change to make DirectoryIndex index.html and it works fine.  I did specify in the mods-available/dir.conf a DirectoryIndex that starts with index.php then index.html but if I tried that in the vhost file, I get an error.

Comment: Check apache error logs regarding why it didn't start.